# Algorithmic help in Python, find pair (x,y) where y/x > const

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I'm building a rather huge real-time odds system, and my bottleneck right now is the actual computation. I have a huge amount of sorted lists, and for each list, I need to find each pair (x,y) where (y/x) > const.

This is what I'm currently doing;

```
for f in reversed(xrange(1, len(odds))):
    found = False
    for s in xrange(0, f):
        try:
            edge = odds[s]/odds[f]
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            continue
        if edge > const:
            found = True
            yield odds[f], odds[s]
        else:
            break
    if not found:
        break
```

The plan being stop whenever I'm certain there are no more pairs. However, I'm doing this for  an average of 40 lists each cycle, and I'm in desperate need of shortening the cycletime. I'm curious about using numpy and see whether than can help me.

The length of each inidividual list is < 50.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**
This is an examplelist with structure

```
(_ , odds1, odds2, odds3, _, _) (_ means not used):
[(260, Decimal('1.45'), Decimal('5.5'), Decimal('4'), 0, 2666298), (35549, Decimal('1.62'), Decimal('4.5'), Decimal('3.5'), 0, 2666298), (35551, Decimal('1.666'), Decimal('4.333'), Decimal('3.6'), 0, 2666298), (35552, Decimal('1.6'), Decimal('3.6'), Decimal('3.35'), 0, 2666298), (35553, Decimal('1.6'), Decimal('3.6'), Decimal('3.35'), 0, 2666298), (54453, Decimal('1.65'), Decimal('4.2'), Decimal('3.6'), 0, 2666298), (56234, Decimal('1.571'), Decimal('4.65'), Decimal('3.9'), 0, 2666298), (56911, Decimal('1.7'), Decimal('4.2'), Decimal('3.15'), 0, 2666298)]
```

I split this list into 3 lists, odds1_list, odds2_list, odds3_list and do computations on them. An example of odds1:

```
[Decimal('1.7'), Decimal('1.666'), Decimal('1.65'), Decimal('1.62'), Decimal('1.6'), Decimal('1.6'), Decimal('1.571'), Decimal('1.45')]
```

Then I need to identify all pairs (x,y) in this list where (y/x > const)

Comment: @TheOne autoadded tag, my bad. Removed now.

Comment: An example would help, since I misread first time. Cyber also seems to have made something that doesn't match your code.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the pairs afterward?

Comment: What should the output be? Your code doesn't seem to be giving what everyone else is answering with.

Comment: Store that pair in a database, output is a tuple.

Comment: "Store that pair in a database" Are you sure that that isn't the bottleneck? Your current code already runs in time proportional to the number of pairs produced.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some list `odds` you can do

```
from itertools import product
list(filter(lambda i: i[0] != 0 and i[1]/i[0] > 2, product(odds,repeat=2)))
```

For example

```
odds = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

Produces

```
[(1.0, 3.0), (1.0, 4.0), (1.0, 5.0), (1.0, 6.0), (1.0, 7.0), (1.0, 8.0), (1.0, 9.0),
 (2.0, 5.0), (2.0, 6.0), (2.0, 7.0), (2.0, 8.0), (2.0, 9.0),
 (3.0, 7.0), (3.0, 8.0), (3.0, 9.0),
 (4.0, 9.0)]
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the example code. Not sure which is broken as I can't seem to deduce the desired result.

Comment: @Cyber While filtering, can I also store the number i[1]/i[0] ?

Answer (score 2):

If the list is sorted, then for each x you can just search the list for the first occurrence of const*x, and all items after that match:

```
import numpy

odds = numpy.arange(10.)
const = 2.5

for x in odds:
    idx = numpy.searchsorted(odds, const*x, side='right')
    for y in odds[idx:]:
        print (x,y)
```

Running gives

```
(0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 2.0)
(0.0, 3.0)
(0.0, 4.0)
(0.0, 5.0)
(0.0, 6.0)
(0.0, 7.0)
(0.0, 8.0)
(0.0, 9.0)
(1.0, 3.0)
(1.0, 4.0)
(1.0, 5.0)
(1.0, 6.0)
(1.0, 7.0)
(1.0, 8.0)
(1.0, 9.0)
(2.0, 6.0)
(2.0, 7.0)
(2.0, 8.0)
(2.0, 9.0)
(3.0, 8.0)
(3.0, 9.0)
```

Comment: For a given x, you want all the ys larger.  You could do it the other way, pick a y and choose all the smaller xs.  You could also keep shrinking the list you're searching as you increase x...

Comment: Ahh, I see, you're yielding x, y -- not y, x.  Yep.  Looks right other than division by 0 problems.  +1 -- This is what I was trying to do but hadn't fully baked it in my head yet.  In any event, to complete the answer (and since OP is asking about the algorithm too), you might also want to note that what numpy is doing is _bisecting_ the array to find the element making it more efficient than a linear search.  (O(logn) rather than O(n)).

Comment: Whoops, needed `side=='right'` to do > rather than >=.  If you don't want x==0 terms, you can continue for x == 0, but formally y/0 is greater than any constant, so it seems like they should stay in.

Comment: This is sweet. Thanks alot, gonna try it out.

Comment: FWIW if time still ends up a bottleneck you can broadcast `searchsorted`: `numpy.searchsorted(odds, const*odds)`.

Comment: Well, formally y/0 is undefined.  The limit of y/epsilon as epsilon goes to 0 is bigger than any constant ;-) -- unless y is 0... then you have an indeterminate form ...

Comment: You can actually make this more output sensitive by noting that the next result has to be after or before idx. Roughly equivalent to something like: `idx = last_idk + numpy.searchsorted(odds[last_idk:], const*x, side='right'). Though thinking there is a better way to actually implement it. You'll also want to go right-to-left instead of left-to-right in the case const < 1.0 (const == 1.0 being a special case perhaps handled separately).

Comment: Typo: Should be last_idx not last_idk.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right: Having a list[start, end), you want to find all indices y
where list[y] > constant * list[x] for each index x in the sorted list of numbers.

An algorithm might be:

```
Set the index y to the beginning of the list.
For each index x:
     Set limit := constant * list[x]
     Binary search an index y' in the range [y, end) where list[y'] > limit
     If the index y' is in the range [y, end):
         Add all pairs list[x], list[y''] where y'' is in the range [y', end]
            to the result set.
         Set y = y'
     Otherwise:
         No further results exist.
```

An implementation in c++ (you accidental tagged it that way):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{
    const unsigned constant = 2;
    std::vector<unsigned> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    auto y = v.begin();
    for(auto x = v.begin(); x < v.end() && y != v.end(); ++x) {
        std::cout << "x = " << *x << ", y: ";
        unsigned limit = constant * (*x);
        y = std::lower_bound(y, v.end(), limit);
        if(y != v.end()) {
            if(*y == limit) ++y;
            for(auto r = y; r < v.end(); ++r)
                std::cout << *r << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that uses numpy and its broadcasting ability:

```
def find_pairs(odds, const):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        pairs = odds[np.column_stack(np.where(odds / odds[:, None] > const))]
    return pairs
```

In theory, the time complexity is O(n**2) (where n is the length of `odds`), but you say n is at most 50, which is small enough that the theoretical complexity might not matter.

Here's a full script that includes some of the other answers (so far):

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np


def find_pairs(odds, const):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        pairs = odds[np.column_stack(np.where(odds / odds[:, None] > const))]
    return pairs


def dursi(odds, const):
    for x in odds:
        idx = np.searchsorted(odds, const*x, side='right')
        for y in odds[idx:]:
            yield (x,y)


def cyber(odds, const):
    return list(filter(lambda i: i[1]/i[0] > const, product(odds, repeat=2)))
```

And here's a timing comparison, using a numpy array with 50 elements:

```
In [122]: const = 1.25

In [118]: odds = np.sort(1 + np.random.rand(50))

In [119]: %timeit find_pairs(odds, const)
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.9 µs per loop

In [120]: %timeit list(dursi(odds, const))
10000 loops, best of 3: 150 µs per loop

In [121]: %timeit cyber(odds, const)
1000 loops, best of 3: 541 µs per loop
```

In this case, the vectorized calculation in `find_pairs` gives enough of an advantage over explicit python loops that it is faster than the others.